# Functionaly Finding Prime Factors with Multiplicity

Tags: beginner, haskell, primes

I am quite new to Haskell so any suggestions are welcome, also I noticed that it works quite slow even for something like

```
prime_factors_mult (2*2*2*2*3*3*3*5*5*7*7*7*7*13*13*13*17*19)
```

Also I may not know of coding conventions/formatting styles and better ways to do things,so you may also help me with that:

```
prime_factors_mult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
prime_factors_mult n =
    reverse . fst $
        foldl
            (\acc@(factors, val) x
                -> if val `mod` x == 0 then
                    let (k, v) = reduce val x in ((x, k) : factors, val `div` v)
                else
                    acc
            )
        ([], n)
        [2 .. floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n]

reduce :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
reduce val x =
    if val `mod` x == 0 then
        let (k, v) = reduce (val `div` x) x in (1 + k, v * x)
    else
        (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we can make your `prime_factors_mult` easier to read if we use `where`:

```
prime_factors_mult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
prime_factors_mult n = reverse . fst . foldl go ([], n) $ candidates
  where
    candidates = [2 .. floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n]
    go acc@(factors, val) x 
      | val `mod` x == 0 = let (k, v) = reduce val x in ((x, k) : factors, val `div` v)
      | otherwise        = acc
```

By the way, Haskell programs use `camelCase`, so `primFactorsMult` would be appropriate. However, does this function really capture your intend? Let us write it as imperative variant for a second:

```python
# pseudo-python
def prime_factors_mult(n):
    result = []

    for i in range(2, sqrt(n)):
        count = 0
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            count = count + 1

        if count > 0:
            result = result.append({i, count})

    return result
```

This is a lot easier to read. We should strive to have an algorithm in Haskell that's just as easy to read, right? By the way, both the pseudo-code as well as your original code contained an error: what happens on `2*7`? \$\sqrt{14} < 7\$, therefore we never check the second prime. We should check that too:

```
# pseudo-python
def prime_factors_mult(n):
    result = []

    for i in range(2, sqrt(n)):
        count = 0
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            count = count + 1

        if count > 0:
            result = result.append({i, count})

    # n is prime at this point:
    if n > 1:
        result = result.append({n, 1})

    return result
```

Allright. Now let's try to get a variant of Haskell that's just as readable. We do that by explicit recursion and then *later* figure out how we can get rid of that:

```
isDivisibleBy n k = n `rem` k == 0

primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult = go 2 
  where
    go _ 1 = []
    go k n 
       | n `isDivisibleBy ` k = (k, m)   : go (k + 1) (n `div` d)
       | n < k * k            = [(n, 1)]
       | otherwise            = go (k + 1) n
      where
        (m, d) = reduce n k
```

Allright, that seems to work. However, do we actually need the `isDivisibleBy` check? No. `reduce` does that for us. So let's get rid of that:

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult = filter ((0 /=) . snd) . go 2 
  where
    go _ 1 = []
    go k n 
       | n <= k    = [(n, 1)]
       | otherwise = (k, m)   : go (k + 1) (n `div` d)
      where
        (m, n') = reduce n k
```

Great. Now we're getting somewhere. We have now two paths we can choose to continue. Either we take our new approach, which is essentially `mapAccumL`, or we inline `reduce`. Let us follow both.

## Mapping with a state

In the code above, we essentially mapped over the list of factors `[2..n]` with a state: the current value of `n`, or rather `` n `div` d ``. It turns out that there is already a function for that kind of operation, namely [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL). We can incorporate into our function:

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult n = filter ((0 /=) . snd) . snd . mapAccumL go n $ 2 : [3,5..n] 
  where
    go n k = (n `div` d, (k, m))
      where
        (m, n') = reduce n k
```

As you can see, we got rid of the recursive calls in `go` and the base case, since that's now handled by `mapAccumL`. We also swapped the arguments, since `mapAccumL` gives the state first. Also, since primes are odd (except for `2`), we've optimized the list slightly.

Unfortunately, we still need to get rid of those with `0` multiplicity. However, what if we didn't return a pair?

## Return factors, one by one

This time, we inline the functionality of `reduce`:

```
primeFactors :: Int -> [Int]
primeFactors n = go 2 
  where
    go _ 1 = []
    go k n = case n `quotRem` k of
               (q, 0) -> k : go k q
               _      ->     go (k + 1) n
```

This will now return a list like `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,7,7,9,9,10]`. By the way, this `quotRem` shows a possible optimization of `reduce`:

```
reduce :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
reduce val x =
    if m == 0 then
        let (k, v) = reduce d x in (1 + k, v * x)
    else
        (0, 1)
 where
    (d, m) = val `divMod` x
```

But when all your numbers are positive, you want to use `quotRem` since it's usually faster. Note that many modern processors do `mod` and `div` at the same time, so using the appropriate function when you ened both results can be a boon.

Back to our prime factors. Now we have the factors. But how can we get the multiplicity? We use [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group):

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . primeFactors
```

Since `group` returns only non-empty lists, we can safely apply `head`.

## Remarks on style

I strongly suggest you to move large lambdas into their own bindings. That made the first variant of `prime_factors_mult` more readable and is the usual style, for example in GHC's code.

Also, if you use both the results of `div` and `mod` use `divMod`, or—if you use positive numbers only or don't want the specific behaviour behind `divMod`—`quotRem`.

Don't be afraid to give something in your code a name. That makes it easier to grasp and to change later. Also, you might notice that a function is reusable.

And, by the way, primes are a "hard" topic, as in: it's not easy to get proper bounds of the numbers you have to check, since you would need to know whether `n` is already a prime, or whether `n / 2` is a prime, or `n / 3` and so on.

## Exercises

- In `go` you can use `(k + 2)` if you handle `2` separately. How can you do that?
- In most `go` functions we can stop much, *much* sooner if `n` is a prime if we know the original `n`. Why? (Hint: what is the largest prime factor that can be in a number? And what is the *second* largest prime factor?)

Comment: The port from pseudo-python drops the `sqrt`, which can be repaired by saying `n < k * k` instead.

Comment: @Gurkenglas the `sqrt` check together with the `n > 1` check are fused into the single `n <= k` check

Comment: Passing a large prime to the first block after "Allright" takes `O(n)`, is what I mean.

Comment: Pssssht. That's part of the exercises, @Gurkenglas ;).

Comment: But he knows this, his original code is already stopping at the sqrt, and your pseudo-python version indicates you know that, you just arbitrarily removed it in the port :S

Comment: @Gurkenglas To be honest I missed it and wasn't at a PC to fix it. Fixed it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58349/discussion-between-gurkenglas-and-zeta).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can pull the condition out of the loop:

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult n = filter ((/=0) . snd) . reverse . fst $
        foldl
            (\(factors, val) x
                -> let (k, v) = reduce val x in ((x, k) : factors, val `div` v)
            )
        ([], n)
        [2 .. floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n]
```

When you need to reverse afterwards, that's a hint you should have folded the other way. But this can even be written in terms of `mapAccumL`:

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult n = filter ((/=0) . snd) . snd $
        mapAccumL
            (\val x
                -> let (k, v) = reduce val x in (val `div` v, (x, k))
            )
        n
        [2 .. floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n]
```

Your implementation is wrong. Some factors may be larger than the square root of `n`, say `17` in `34`.

More might follow.

Edit: This is not good. Where are my heuristics leading me? Send help ._.

```
primeFactorsMult :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
primeFactorsMult = evalState $ fmap (filter ((/=0) . snd)) $
  mapStateT (fromJustNote "traverseMany") $ (`traverseMany` [2..]) $ \x -> do
    guard =<< gets (/=1)
    exponent <- fmap length $ many $ do
      guard =<< gets ((==0) . (`mod` x))
      modify (`div` x)
    pure (x, exponent)

traverseMany :: Alternative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
traverseMany f [] = pure []
traverseMany f (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> traverseMany f xs <|> pure []
```

Comment: Honest question: why do you dump `State`, `Alternative`, `guard`, `=<<` and `pure` on a [tag:beginner]? Guessing from their code, they might not have learned about `Applicative`, maybe not even `Functor` yet. This is a trend with your beginner answers and I'm genuinely curious about that.